# Save Parquet file from Lambda to S3 with java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet

I have a use case where I need to save a parquet file from Lambda to S3.
I need to store the events triggered in the Lambda function in append mode..

I tried with Avro but it doesn't permit to store the data in append mode in a same parquet file..

Till now, I found that just spark permit to store data in parquet file in append mode... Then, I could use Lambda to submit a spark job that store the data.
What do you think about this possible solution?

However, really doesn't exists a solution without the use of spark?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't append data to any file stored in S3, no matter the format. Sorry. It's just one of those differences between S3 and a filesystem.